# Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf not working for numbers

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario**

I have the following code to check how many times a certain value appears in a column. Here poRange is a range defined earlier and poValueCheck is a value defined earlier by the program.

`iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(poRange), Trim(poValueCheck) & "*")`

**Problem**

Everything works fine except if I need to search for the occurrence of a number in that range. If I need to search a pure number which exist in the poRange, iVal getting 0 even though there is a similar number exists.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to usage of wild card searching of numbers which eventually changing the search value from number format to string format and thus numbers in the range will not be counted. In other words, when I search a number 1234 with a wild card search `Trim(1234) & "*"`, the number 1234 will not be counted anymore.

Thus I tried to change cell format to text. But then I realized even after changed cell format to text, those values already entered before will not change to text format. So I changed all the numbers in the column to text by adding an apostrophe symbol in front of all numbers by using a simple macro below by giving it in a loop.

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "'" & ActiveCell.Value
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Now I am able to count even the numbers using `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`

Answer (score 0):

the expression `Trim(poValueCheck) & "*"` returns a string. So, when you look for "1234*" the number 1234 will not be found. You might try something like this:-

```
Dim Crit as variant

Crit = Trim(poValueCheck)
If IsNumeric Crit Then
    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(poRange), Crit)
Else
    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(poRange), Crit & "*")
End If
```

Comment: I tried this method earlier. But the problem with this is, i will loose the capability of wild card searching. I need to key the exact number in order to find the occurrence. I need the wild card search capability even if it is a number

Comment: In that case you would have to change the numbers in the searched range to Text.

Comment: i changed the format of those cells to text. But still it is not working. Also i tried to change the variable poValueCheck to string. But still not working

Comment: @Anu Changing the format of the cell does not change the data type of previously entered values.

Comment: If you know that your numbers have, say, 8 digits you can create artificial search criteria. Like user enters 1234, `Crit = Val(Left(Crit & "00000000",8))`. You can then search for values >=Crit

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  You are absolutely right. I just realized this. I entered new numbers into the cells which are formatted as text and then program is finding it correctly. But those data already keyed in, even though i changed cell format to text, but no impact which is bad! Is there any way we can change the format of already keyed in values?

Comment: @Variatus No buddy. I can't tell exactly how many numbers user key in. It is totally random

Comment: @Anu Something like:  `myCell.NumberFormat = "@" :myCell.Value = myCell.Value` should do it for constants.

Comment: The suggestion was that you might know how many numbers the search should return. If you know that the searched for item has 8 digits the formula I suggested will create an 8-digit number regardless of how many digits the user enters.

Comment: I wrote a simple macro to convert all the numbers to text by adding the apostrophe symbol ' at the beginning and thus converted existing data to text format. Problem solved now. Thanks guys for helping me out